# c++ copy-construct instance into map

Tags: c++, dictionary, copy-constructor

Here is a code with a simple class Foo that in instanciated and then inserted into a map.
I don't understand how the copy-constructor is called when inserting foo into fooMap.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
    public:

        //default constructor
        Foo() {
            name_ = string("Undefined") + suffix();
            cout << "Constructing Foo '"<< name_ << "'" << endl;
        };

        //constructor with arg
        Foo(const char* name): name_(name) {
            cout << "Constructing Foo '" << name << "'" << endl;
        };

        //default const copy-constructor
        Foo(const Foo &foo) {
            name_ = foo.get_name() + suffix();
            cout << "Copying const Foo '" << foo.get_name() << "' into Foo '" << name_ << "'" << endl;
        }

        //default destructor
        ~Foo() {
            cout << "Destroying Foo '" << name_ << "'" << endl;
        }

        //getting name
        const string get_name() const {
            return name_;
        };

        //setting name
        void set_name(string new_name){
            name_ = new_name;
        }

        //suffix for name
        string suffix() {
            static int cmp=0;
            char ch[2];
            sprintf(ch,"%d",cmp++);
            return string(ch);
        }

    private:
        string name_;
};

int main() {

    typedef map<string, Foo> FooMapType;
    FooMapType fooMap;

    cout << "1:\n";
    Foo foo("bar");

    cout << "\n2:\n";
    fooMap["bar"] = foo;

    cout << "\n3:\n";
    cout << fooMap["bar"].get_name() << endl;
    foo.set_name("baz");

    cout << "\n4:\n";
```

The output is:

```
1:
Constructing Foo 'bar'

2:
Constructing Foo 'Undefined0'
Copying const Foo 'Undefined0' into Foo 'Undefined01'
Copying const Foo 'Undefined01' into Foo 'Undefined012'
Destroying Foo 'Undefined01'
Destroying Foo 'Undefined0'

3:
bar

4:
Destroying Foo 'baz'
Destroying Foo 'bar'
```

But I expected the foo copy-constructor to be called, causing the output:

```
Copying const Foo 'bar' into Foo 'Undefined0'
```

Comment: What happens if you change "name" to "name_" when printing out the object's name in the constructor with arguments?Also you should be more consistent-you shouldn't use the member data's name in some functions and the argument's name in others.

Comment: Here is one similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771449/stl-map-value-constructors

Comment: Use `insert` instead of `[]`.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing assignment, not copy construction in the line `fooMap["bar"] = foo;` Override `Foo &operator=(const Foo&)` to see that happening.

The default construction is the creation of the initial item you would do the assignment into.

The copies you're seeing are probably internal to the map implementation - putting it into the appropriate place in the tree. There are more than I would have expected.

Answer (score 3):

`map::operator[]` returns a reference to a value member so the following statement:

```
fooMap["bar"] = foo;
```

can be interpreted as:

```
Foo& fooRef = fooMap["bar"]; // (1)
fooRef = foo;                // (2)
```

In (1) `map::operator[]` is executed and in (2) `Foo::operator=`.

If given key does not exist in the map, `map::operator[]` creates a new element - a pair made of the provided key and a value object constructed with default constructor. (Key type is `std::string` and value type is `Foo` in your example). If given key exists, it just returns a reference to the value object.

Line (2) changes value through its reference.

If you have a look at the implementation of `map::operator[]` (I am providing Microsoft's one here, from STL library that comes with VS2010) you can see that it calls `map::insert()`
under the bonnet, providing it temporary object `value_type` which is again created from temporary object `mapped_type`:

```
mapped_type& operator[](const key_type& _Keyval)
{   
    // find element matching _Keyval or insert with default mapped
    iterator _Where = this->lower_bound(_Keyval);

    if (_Where == this->end() || this->comp(_Keyval, this->_Key(_Where._Mynode())))
       _Where = this->insert(_Where, value_type(_Keyval, mapped_type()));

    return ((*_Where).second);
}
```

`value_type` is basically pair I mentioned above and `mapped_type` is `Foo` in your case.
`mapped_type()` creates temporary object by calling its default constructor. This matches the second default constructor in your output (the first one is called when local variable `foo` is created). `value_type`'s constructor uses `mapped_type`'s copy constructor in order to create its instance of value member. This matches the first call of `Foo`'s copy constructor. There is another call of this constructor in your log and in order to find its source we need to dig a bit deeper into `map::operator[]`...actually into `insert` method it calls:

```
template<class _Valty>
typename _STD tr1::enable_if<!_STD tr1::is_same<const_iterator, typename _STD tr1::remove_reference<_Valty>::type>::value, iterator>::type
insert(const_iterator _Where, _Valty&& _Val)
{   
   // try to insert node with value _Val using _Where as a hint
   return (_Insert(_Where, this->_Buynode(_STD forward<_Valty>(_Val))));
}
```

Map is implemented as a tree and we can see that inner `_Insert` method inserts a new instance of tree node, created with `_Buynode()`:

```
template<class _Valty>
_Nodeptr _Buynode(_Valty&& _Val)
{   
   // allocate a node with defaults
   _Nodeptr _Wherenode = _Buynode();
   ...
   _Cons_val(this->_Alval, _STD addressof(this->_Myval(_Wherenode)), _STD forward<_Valty>(_Val));
   ...
   return (_Wherenode);
}
```

Tree node encapsulates pair object - map's element so it's creation involves creation of another copy of our pair - `_Val` and this is the point where another call of `Foo`'s copy constructor takes place.

`map::operator[]` call created two temporary objects containing `Foo` and on return these objects were destroyed so therefore you can see two destructor calls in your output.

If you implement `Foo::operator=` and put a trace inside it, you would be able to see that this method is called as well (line (2)).

If you later map the same key to some other `Foo` object, you would have only `Foo::operator=` executed because map's element for that key is already created and only value is changed through its reference.

Answer (score 0):

A good question, I get the same behaviour.  The specifics of our (and maybe all?) STL implementations create default objects then use another method to copy the data across.

Standing back, it can be seen that once the insert (or in your case operator[]) method has been called a copy of the original object *does exist in the map*, and that may well be all that the standard promises.

Answer (score 0):

`fooMap["bar"] = foo` results in a default construction, two copies and an assignment.

The default construction is required as there is no string-foo pair for the key `"bar"`.

The first copy comes about as a pair is constructed with key `"bar"` and value copied from the default constructed `foo` that's just been made.

The second copy comes about as the pair is then copied into the map.

The assignment then assigns the value in the map to `foo`.

An STL implementation using R-Value semantics in C++11 could make this much more efficient.